# Django-compressor not working after first compress statement

Tags: django, django-compressor

I have a website with various js files, and i'm using django-compressor like so:

```
{% compress js %}
{% endcompress %}

{% compress js %}
{% endcompress %}
```

For some reason its only creating the FIRST js file. I have my app hosted on an EC2. I can see the first file there. The second file appears when I do a view source on the page, however, the file itself doens't exist (I get a 404 when I click on the link to the second js file). Is  there anything I'm doing wrong? I have my settings as per below:

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = not DEBUG
COMPRESS_PARSER = 'compressor.parser.BeautifulSoupParser'
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = ['compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter']
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
```

It's working perfectly for css files...but failing on any other js file after the first compress flag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly have no idea what happened. this used to work perfectly, but randomly stopped out of no where! I did the following and it worked:

```
python manage.py compress --force
```

This basically forces it to compress all files; normally `django-compressor` ignores files that have not changed and have been compressed already.